# 'method Invocation failed' recently began occurring for processing a system.object

Tags: powershell, object, indexof, implicit

I was wondering if there was some sort of update to PowerShell that would have caused the following to begin throwing invocation failed because it stopped implicitly recognizing objects as strings. The `IndexOf` method had been used to dynamically build query strings from datasets.

The following statement had executed with no problems everyday for the past couple of years:

```
$phishEvents | %{
....
   Foreach($name in $names.name) {
     if ($_.$($name).IndexOf("'") -gt 0) { $_.$($name) = $_.$($name).Replace("'","''")}
   }
...
}
```

Today it began throwing an exception stating it no longer recognized the `IndexOf` for those fields that were not string.

I ended up wrapping the statement to check for type prior to the statement - as follows:

```
   if (($_.$($name).GetType().FullName) -eq "System.String") {
     if ($_.$($name).IndexOf("'") -gt 0) { $_.$($name) = $_.$($name).Replace("'","''")}
   }
```

The question I have is was there some sort of change that now prevents PowerShell from this type of implicit conversion?  I know that is is poor practice to rely on implicit conversion for logic, however; I was really curious to know if any others noticed the same issue.

Using `PSVersion 5.1.19041.1682`

Thanks!

Comment: Im wondering how could `Foreach($name in $names.name) {` enumerate anything in your first snippet when `$names` is nowhere to be found

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed in that regard:

- Calling a *method* on a variable value / expression result only ever succeeds (and only ever has) if that value / result is of a .NET type that actually has such a method.

A simpler and more efficient way to test a given value for being an instance of a given .NET type is to use the [`-is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators):

```bash
if ($_.$name -is [string] -and $_.$name.IndexOf("'") -gt 0) { 
  $_.$name = $_.$name.Replace("'","''")}
}
```

Note the streamlined logic and the simplification of `$_.$($name)` to `$_.$name`